# Login Stored Procedure returning NULL value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure to check login credentials and return a value accordingly. But I am getting a NULL returned.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Proc_CheckUser]
    @UserID   VARCHAR(50),
    @Password VARCHAR(50)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @ReturnVal VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @PasswordOld VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @Type VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @IP  NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @DBPassword NVARCHAR(50)
    SET @DBPassword = Hashbytes('SHA1',@Password)

    SELECT 
       @PasswordOld = Password,
       @Type = ClientType,
       @IP = IPAddress
    FROM   
       Clients
    WHERE  
       username = @userid  
       AND Password = @DBPassword

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT=0)
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnVal = '1|Incorrect Username'

        INSERT INTO FailedLogins(Username, Password, ClientType, Reason, IPAddress)
        VALUES(@UserID, Hashbytes('SHA1', @Password), @Type, 'Invalid Username', @IP)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (@PasswordOld <> @DBPassword)
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnVal = '1|Incorrect Password'

            INSERT INTO FailedLogins(Username, Password, ClientType, Reason, IPAddress)
            VALUES(@UserID, Hashbytes('SHA1', @Password), @Type, 'Invalid Password', @IP)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnVal = '0|Logged in successfully' + '|' + rtrim(cast(@Type as char))

            INSERT INTO SuccessfulLogins(Username, Password, ClientType, Reason, IPAddress)
            VALUES(@UserID, Hashbytes('SHA1', @Password), @Type, 'Valid Login Credentials Provided', @IP)
        END 
     END

     SELECT @ReturnVal
```

Can anyone suggest me a more suitable way to write the stored procedure?

Thank You

Comment: After declaring '@DBPassword', Set "@DBPassword=HashBytes('SHA1',@Password)". i think you are not assigning any value to variable '@dbPassword' and hence you are not entering in IF statement hence '@ReturnVal' returns NULL value.

Comment: @PareshJ Thanks ..now it works fine but I am getting NULL after I enter a Valid Username

Comment: NULL value inplace of Username while inserting??

Comment: @PareshJ I am sorry .I mean to say when I entered an INVALID USERNAME it returns NULL

Comment: @user2614235 : the NULL return for invalid username is due to the issues I mentioned in my response. I will update the answer explaining why.

Comment: Of Course!! It will since your ROWCOUNT does not contains BEGIN and END blocks and neither your stored procedure have Begin and End block. Please check it.

Comment: @PareshJ I Added Begin And End Blocks but still getting NULL

Comment: @PareshJ : the stored procedure itself does not require BEGIN / END tags; they are optional.

Comment: @srutzky: Incase of INVALID USERNAME, SET @ReturnVal='1|Incorrect Username', NULL is not getting concatenated to result null.

Comment: @PareshJ : you are partially correct. The NULL is not being concatenated at that step. But due to the lack of BEGIN / END with a RETURN in there, the following IF block is executed, which falls into the ELSE which re-sets @ReturnVal to another string which trys to concatenate `@Type` which is NULL, resulting in the NULL being returned.

Comment: @srutzky: You are Right!!! +1

Comment: @user2614235 : please see my updated answer. Your updates to the code in the question are missing a critical piece: either the SELECT and RETURN in the BEGIN / END _or_ the ELSE after the new BEGIN / END tags. Also, you need to add a WHERE condition for `AND [Password] = @DBPassword` in the SELECT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few problems:

1. It makes no sense to have `and @DBPassword=HashBytes('SHA1',@Password)` in the WHERE condition. It is an assignment and needs to happen *before* the SELECT so that it can be used *in* the SELECT. So do this above the SELECT:

   ```
   SET @DBPassword=HashBytes('SHA1',@Password);
   ```
2. `@DBPassword` is declared as `NVARCHAR(50)` yet [HASHBYTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) returns VARBINARY. So even if this is "working", it is not intuitive to others in terms of maintaining the process.
3. WHERE condition in the SELECT should be:

   ```
   and [Password] = @DBPassword
   ```
4. The `IF @@ROWCOUNT=0` condition is not wrapped in BEGIN and END tags. Hence the `SET @ReturnVal='1|Incorrect Username'` is the only statement controlled by the `IF`, and the `INSERT INTO FailedLogins` is *always* executed no matter what the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` is.
5. There is no `RETURN` in what should be the `BEGIN ... END` block of the `IF @@ROWCOUNT=0` condition, hence the following `IF (@PasswordOld<>@DBPassword)` condition *always* executes. If `@@ROWCOUNT` is actually 0, then `@PasswordOld` will be `NULL` which evaluates to `false` and hence the `ELSE` portion of the `IF` will execute
6. For your purposes here, returning `@ReturnVal` is fine, but it might possibly be cleaner to declare `@ReturnVal` as an `OUTPUT` param and grab the value that way rather than from a result set. But that is not a functional difference, unlike the above items.

The reason for getting a NULL returned when passing in an invalid Username is mainly that you are not handling the `IF @@ROWCOUNT=0` correctly:

- it is missing BEGIN / END, and
- it is missing the RETURN within the missing BEGIN / END tags, hence
- the `IF (@PasswordOld<>@DBPassword)` block is entered, which in turn
- falls into the ELSE condition due to `@PassworldOld` being NULL (due to no matching row from the SELECT which sets `@PasswordOld`), hence
- the `SET @ReturnVal='0|Logged in Successfully' +'|'+ rtrim(cast(@Type as char))` statement executes, but again, due to no rows returned from the SELECT which sets `@Type`, `@Type` is still `NULL`, and
- concatenating a `NULL` into a string returns `NULL`, which is what `@ReturnVal` is set to.

---

The main fix should look like:

```
SET @DBPassword = HashBytes('SHA1',@Password);

SELECT @PasswordOld = Password,
       @Type = ClientType,
       @IP = IPAddress
FROM   Clients
WHERE  username = @UserID
AND    Password = @DBPassword; 

IF (@@ROWCOUNT=0)
BEGIN
  SET @ReturnVal = '1|Incorrect Username';

  INSERT INTO FailedLogins(Username,Password,ClientType,Reason,IPAddress)
  VALUES(@UserID, @DBPassword, @Type, 'Invalid Username', @IP);

  SELECT @ReturnVal AS [ReturnVal];

  RETURN; -- exit the proc.
END;
```

An alternative to the SELECT and RETURN within that BEGIN / END block would be to instead do an ELSE *after* that BEGIN / END block, which would encapsulate the following IF statement. That is just a matter of preference. Meaning:

```
IF (@@ROWCOUNT=0)
BEGIN
  SET @ReturnVal = '1|Incorrect Username';

  INSERT INTO FailedLogins(Username,Password,ClientType,Reason,IPAddress)
  VALUES(@UserID, @DBPassword, @Type, 'Invalid Username', @IP);
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
   IF (@PasswordOld!=Hashbytes('SHA1',@Password))
   BEGIN
      ...
   END;
   ELSE
   BEGIN
      ...
   END;
END;

SELECT @ReturnVal;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr srutzky for helping me and  for explaining the concepts.I'll update the code, would you please edit the code ?

Comment: Exactly!! +1 for this. Need to exit the proc when one condition fails.

Comment: @srutzky thank you once again.I used your 2nd code example and now it is returning Invalid Username now even after entering a valid username.Ill update my code.Please check what is the issue.This SP is driving me nuts

Comment: @user2614235 I need to sign off as it's 3 A.M and I needed to be asleep 2 hours ago ; -). But the problem is at least now narrowed down to one or both of the WHERE conditions not matching. Make sure the datatypes match and that HASHBYTES is returning the expected value.

Comment: Ok Mr srutzky Thanks a lot for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

last forget `Return` Keyword add `return` keyword

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Proc_CheckUser]
 @UserID   VARCHAR(50),
 @Password VARCHAR(50)
 AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @ReturnVal VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @PasswordOld VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @Type VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @IP  NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @DBPassword NVARCHAR(50)


    SELECT @PasswordOld = Password,@Type=ClientType,@IP=IPAddress
    FROM   Clients
    WHERE  username = @userid and @DBPassword=HashBytes('SHA1',@Password)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
      SET @ReturnVal='1|Incorrect Username'
      INSERT INTO FailedLogins(Username,Password,ClientType,Reason,IPAddress)
      VALUES(@UserID,@DBPassword,@Type,'Invalid Username',@IP)

    IF (@PasswordOld<>@DBPassword)
      BEGIN
      SET @ReturnVal='1|Incorrect Password'
      INSERT INTO FailedLogins(Username,Password,ClientType,Reason,IPAddress)
      VALUES(@UserID,@DBPassword,@Type,'Invalid Password',@IP)
      END

    ELSE
      BEGIN
      SET @ReturnVal='0|Logged in Successfully' +'|'+ rtrim(cast(@Type as char))
      INSERT INTO SuccessfulLogins(Username,Password,ClientType,Reason,IPAddress)
      VALUES(@UserID,@DBPassword,@Type,'Valid Login Credentials Provided',@IP)
      END 


    SELECT @ReturnVal
Return
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.But it is still returning NULL Even after adding return

Comment: @user2614235 and Denish: `RETURN` has absolutely nothing to do with anything. A proc will always return. when not explicitly calling `RETURN`, or when calling `RETURN` by itself (as you are doing here), it will issue `RETURN 0`. But it has no effect here.

Comment: @srutzky Thanks for replying.As was going to say RETURN has nothing to do with the Stored Procedure returning a NULL value.So what changes would you suggest in my code?